# "Had gone" vs "Were gone"

Tags: word-usage, active-vs-passive

I'm writing a text and I'm wondering if I can change "The week before, we had gone to a British Palace" by "The week before, we were gone to a British Palace". It seems to me that "were gone" cannot be followed by something, right? Plus, I think "we were gone" means disappear.

Comment: I've edited to remove the "I'm new here", and "Emma" and "Thanks".  Your name is automatically added by the system. And the best way to say thanks is to accept the best answer to your problem.

Comment: You don't need a capital P to start 'palace'.

Comment: The answer has disappeared. What happened?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to change it to **were gone** people would understand what you meant but would assume that you were not a fluent English speaker. As you say, **were gone** is generally used in the sense of **had disappeared**.

Your original statement using the past perfect is correct. The week before you **had gone** to a British palace. As was earlier pointed out, you are describing an event that occurred before the main topic.

Depending on the context other people might say that the week before **they went to a British palace**, which would also be acceptable.

I have copied below the earlier comment from user105719 as I think it is a useful guide to usage that most people would no longer be familiar with.

*There's another, somewhat archaic usage meaning "taken and therefore absent." Try EH's A Farewell to Arms: "The horses were gone to Rome and there was no more racing." – user105719 1 hour ago*